# Run application program after linux bootup on ARM

Tags: c, linux, arm, boot

I have loaded bootloader and ported linux on my ARM processor Am3892. Now i need to run one application program, but i don't have any console interface to run it after booting linux. Is there any possibility that my program will execute as soon as the linux will bootup? Please reply.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Pass the path and application name to the kernel as a boot parameter for init, the kernel will only start the init process itself (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_startup_process). Traditionally this application then handles starting daemons, geTTYs, etc.

Most boot loaders allow you to specify a path for the init app as part of the configuration for where to find the kernel.

e.g. /boot/vmlinuz-n.n.n init=/path/to/theapp

If you let us know what boot loader you're using then perhaps we could more specific. Otherwise look up how to pass linux kernel arguments to your boot loader.

Comment: can it be possible just by making any entry in any init or rc files? just like how default start up programs get started in linux?

Comment: You could, it depends how embedded your linux is. If he really only has a kernel, a file system and one app, then you can only do it by setting the init kernel argument to the path to his app. If however it's a full file system and some form of init (in-house, or standard) then yes, just start the app via the init configuration as normal. Porting and ARM made me think mega-embedded.

Comment: It should be possible to call your own app from any file located in /etc/init.d/ folder. You can do it in rcS file or create your own file with S and numeral prefix (like S90user). remember to set it executable.

Comment: @BartlomiejGrzeskowiak hey thanks this is what, which i was thinking..!!